# How to give specific color to particular range in 3D scatter graph using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am using 3D scatter graph in highchart. I wanted to plot specific color to y-axis based on each range like 0-5 red color 5-10 green and so on ..

Below is the jsfiddle code.

[JS Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/m9u8wd64/3/)

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Reading',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [
        [1, 6, 5], [8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8], [5, 7, 7], [6, 9, 6],
        [7, 0, 5], [2, 3, 3], [3, 9, 8], [3, 6, 5], [4, 9, 4], [2, 3, 3],
        [6, 9, 9], [0, 7, 0], [7, 7, 9], [7, 2, 9], [0, 6, 2], [4, 6, 7],
        [3, 7, 7], [0, 1, 7], [2, 8, 6], [2, 3, 7], [6, 4, 8], [3, 5, 9],
        [7, 9, 5], [3, 1, 7], [4, 4, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 1, 6], [6, 8, 5],
        [6, 6, 7], [4, 1, 1], [7, 2, 7], [7, 7, 0], [8, 8, 9], [9, 4, 1],
        [8, 3, 4], [9, 8, 9], [3, 5, 3], [0, 2, 4], [6, 0, 2], [2, 1, 3],
        [5, 8, 9], [2, 1, 1], [9, 7, 6], [3, 0, 2], [9, 9, 0], [3, 4, 8],
        [2, 6, 1], [8, 9, 2], [7, 6, 5], [6, 3, 1], [9, 3, 1], [8, 9, 3],
        [9, 1, 0], [3, 8, 7], [8, 0, 0], [4, 9, 7], [8, 6, 2], [4, 3, 0],
        [2, 3, 5], [9, 1, 4], [1, 1, 4], [6, 0, 2], [6, 1, 6], [3, 8, 8],
        [8, 8, 7], [5, 5, 0], [3, 9, 6], [5, 4, 3], [6, 8, 3], [0, 1, 5],
        [6, 7, 3], [8, 3, 2], [3, 8, 3], [2, 1, 6], [4, 6, 7], [8, 9, 9],
        [5, 4, 2], [6, 1, 3], [6, 9, 5], [4, 8, 2], [9, 7, 4], [5, 4, 2],
        [9, 6, 1], [2, 7, 3], [4, 5, 4], [6, 8, 1], [3, 4, 0], [2, 2, 6],
        [5, 1, 2], [9, 9, 7], [6, 9, 9], [8, 4, 3], [4, 1, 7], [6, 2, 5],
        [0, 4, 9], [3, 5, 9], [6, 9, 1], [1, 9, 2]]
}]
```

How to pass color in data which is used to generate the graph?

After using the zones

```
  zoneAxis: 'y',
  zones: [{value: 10, color: 'red'}, {value: 20, color: 'green'}, {value: 30, color: 'orange'}],
```

I am getting following output :
[image]

Comment: Each range does not really say a lot, since you have 3 axis to do this to. How do you envision these points colored: [0,0,10], [0,10,0], [10,0,0], [10,10,10] ? If you wanted to color one axis, this is the way to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/m9u8wd64/7/

Comment: @ewolden - I wanted to plot for y axis based on data range ie in y-axis if the value is 0-5  then red color , 5-10 then green color and so on ..

Comment: So, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/m9u8wd64/9/ ?

Comment: @ewolden - This is the actual code http://jsfiddle.net/ahqoft0u/2/ : after giving the range the top one remains same in different color

Comment: I can unfortunatley not reach the ajax address. However, if you have several series, and want them all colored like this, add the zones and zoneAxis config to plotOptions.

Comment: @ewolden : Thank you...Its working fine. And i have one more doubt...How to add legends to this..To display that this color belongs to this range..

Comment: Adding legends to this with this formatting is difficult. It would be easier to split it into 3 series based on y value before adding it to the chart, then color each series. Then it is easy to add it to legend.

Comment: For the record, this does not work when you use a non-default style.

Answer (score 0):

After adding zones its working !!!

```
      series: [{
              name: '3D Scatter Graph',
              colorByPoint: true,
              zoneAxis: 'y',
              zones: [{value: 50, color: 'red'}, {value: 100, color: 'green'}, {value: 300, color: 'orange'},{value: 500, color: 'black'}],
              data: Json_data
          }]
```